# How to get a list of all leaves under a node in a dendrogram?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I made a dendrogram using scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram,
using the following generated data:

`a = np.random.multivariate_normal([10, 0], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[100,])
b = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 20], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[50,])
c = np.random.multivariate_normal([8, 2], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[80,])
X = np.concatenate((a, b, c),)`

creating the linkage function:

`from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
Z = linkage(X, 'ward')`

and then:

`dendrogram(
    Z,
    truncate_mode='lastp',  # show only the last p merged clusters
    p=5,  # show only the last p merged clusters
    show_leaf_counts=False,  # otherwise numbers in brackets are counts
    leaf_rotation=90.,
    leaf_font_size=12.,
    show_contracted=True,  # to get a distribution impression in truncated branches
)`

Now, I have overall 230 observations in my data that were splitted to p=5 clusters. I want to have, for each cluster, a list of all row indices of all observations that are in it. In addition, I'd like to know the structure of the hierarchy above those 5 clusters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to clustering and dendrogram. So welcome to point out error if there is any.

```
# put X in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1']=X[:,0]
df['col2']=X[:,1]

index=[]
for i in range(len(X)):
    elem = 'A' + str(i)
    index.append(elem)

df['index'] = index
print(df.shape)
df.head()
```

[image]

```
Z = linkage(X, 'ward')

dendrogram(
Z,
truncate_mode='lastp',  # show only the last p merged clusters
p=5,  # show only the last p merged clusters
show_leaf_counts=True,  # otherwise numbers in brackets are counts
leaf_rotation=90.,
leaf_font_size=12.,
show_contracted=True,  # to get a distribution impression in truncated branches
);
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# retrieve elements in each cluster
label = fcluster(Z, 5, criterion='maxclust')

df_clst = pd.DataFrame()
df_clst['index']  = df['index']
df_clst['label']  = label

# print them
for i in range(5):
   elements = df_clst[df_clst['label']==i+1]['index'].tolist()  
   size = len(elements)
   print('\n Cluster {}: N = {}  {}'.format(i+1, size, elements))
```

[image]